# If Starman is heading to Mars, why is he still spinning so we see the earth?

Tags: launch, spacex, falcon-heavy

If Starman is heading to Mars, why is he still spinning so we see the earth?
 Shouldn't he always be pointing away from the earth?

Comment: @osgx This comment should be an/the answer. At the time of the stream the roadster was not heading to Mars but merely waiting in earth orbit for the next burn. And after the burn its orientation or rotation doesn't really matter any more. This isn't Star Wars where you somehow need your engines to maintain speed, they are only used for relatively short durations to accelerate.

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense if you haven't been following SpaceX's activity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starman and its stylish choice of transportation are sitting atop the second stage:

[image]
<sup>[source](https://www.autoevolution.com/news/falcon-heavy-official-launch-animation-a-wish-come-true-for-dreamers-123282.html#agal_0)</sup>

The stage itself may be using [spin stabilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-stabilisation), which helps by providing gyroscopic stability and thermal distribution. If you [observe the live feed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBr2kKAHN6M), you may notice that it is spinning in a counter-clockwise motion.

Once disconnected from the second stage, the payload may preserve the original momentum.

Comment: Ono, where is the sound in the live feed?

Comment: @osgx While it would theoretically be possible to capture vibrations transmitted by the structure itself, I fear our brave Starman is right now in a medium devoid of enough air to transmit acoustic waves. A pity, I know; It probably would like to have Rocket Man blasting through the void.

Comment: So, for clarification, is the entire stage itself spinning? Or is the car on a platform that is rotating?

Comment: @hwp08 yes, the whole stage is spinning, albeit slowly.

Comment: @hwp08 its like a screw. the booster is where the screwdriver goes and the car punctures the wood

Comment: Will the payload disconnect from the second stage? Or is it bolted on? What happens to the second stage? Will it stay in orbit forever?

Comment: @nmit026 yes. The car itself is connected to an adapter, but the adapter disconnected from the 2nd stage: http://www.collectspace.com/images/news-020618a-lg.jpg

Comment: This answer says they're still connected: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24793/15719

Comment: So does this article: https://www.mercurynews.com/2018/02/06/you-wont-believe-what-happens-to-that-tesla-roadster-inside-todays-spacex-launch/ Thanks for your original answer about spin.

Comment: @nmit026 oh, you're right - my original source was corrected too. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

And though from our point of view Starman is spinning in motion ...He is still moving in a trajectory away from earth ....very slowly from the cameras point of view . He will be at Mars in October 2018 .

Watch this Video to further Understand how this works :