# In what position is the Tesla Roadster mounted on the SpaceX Falcon Heavy?

Tags: spacecraft, falcon-heavy

I've been looking at the live streams but it's difficult to tell.  How is the Tesla mounted on the Falcon Heavy?  Is parallel or perpendicular to the axis of the rocket?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pictured in answer https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24905, it is like 45 degrees to the rocket axis.

[image: tesla roadster on second stage of falcon heavy]

https://www.autoevolution.com/news/falcon-heavy-official-launch-animation-a-wish-come-true-for-dreamers-123282.html#agal_0

or before launch, cropped from https://www.instagram.com/p/BezcvpzAgYI/?taken-by=elonmusk

[image: tesla roadster on payload adapter before launch on top of Falcon Heavy]