# How deep into space will the live feed from Starman remain active?

Tags: launch, spacex, mars, rockets, falcon-heavy

Assuming they keep it streaming for us to watch, at what distance will it no longer broadcast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not very far. The batteries were reported to only last for 12 hours, and they are coasting for the first 6 hours, before it does the final boost to adjust to the final orbit.

How far can it get in 6 hours?  Not very far.  11 km/s was the ultimate top speed we heard so less than 250,000km.

Comment: If they turned off the cameras, would it be possible to save battery to broadcast when Starman cruises past Mars?

Comment: @BruceWayne have a look at this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24798/12102) for some thoughts on that.

Comment: @BruceWayne It won't cruise past mars.

Comment: Does that battery include the music playing?

Comment: @RomanReiner yeah, I just found that out. Starman will cruise past/through Mars' orbit, but not the planet itself right?

Comment: The live view is still on after 24 hours.